# DQL query in Symfony for ManyToOne unidirectional relationship

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

```
class MenuItem
{
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\Id 
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/ 
protected $id; 

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MenuCategory")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="menu_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $catagory; 
}
```

Category class

```
class MenuCategory
{
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/ 
protected $id; 

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string")
*/ 
protected $name; 

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
protectted $ordering;
}
```

I want to query all of the items ordered by the ordering property in the category. Here is my query that I tried. I am new to SQL/DQL and am not sure how to access the ordering property in the query. This query is the the MenuItemRepository.php file.

```
class MenuItemRepository extends EntityRepository
{ 
public function getOrderedMenu() 
{ 
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->select('i')
        ->orderBy('i.catagory.ordering', 'ASC') //????
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
}
}
```

Is there a way to get all the items orderedBy ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *cat* **a** *gory* in your `orderBy` clause instead of *cat* **e** *gory*!

Further **protectted** instead of **protected** in front of your `$ordering` property.

The following should work:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->leftJoin('i.category', 'c')
    ->orderBy('c.ordering', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```